# Invoking call hierarchy from eclipse plug in

Tags: eclipse, plugins, call-hierarchy

I want to write an eclipse plugin which can take a list of class names and return me a table of classes where they are being referenced in a given project.
I was thinking if i can use eclipse cal hierarchy. But not sure how to invoke this command. could someone help me with this, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [OpenCallHierarchyAction](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/IDE-Eclipse/jdt/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/callhierarchy/OpenCallHierarchyAction.java.htm) class of the org.eclipse.jdt.ui.internal.callhierarchy Package. This is internal Eclipse source code, but the code in the run(ITextSelection selection) method should be interesting to you.

Comment: Kool this is what i was searchin for. although adding reference of this into plug in project needs to include "org.eclipse.jdt.ui.source" in dependency.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want something like References->Workspace (Control+Shift+G) rather than the call hierarchy?

Have you used this option before? It uses FindReferencesAction, take a look at this class and you can see it building up a search query based on the currently selected IJavaElement.

Could you use this as a basic for a search query on multiple IJavaElements? Or do you want your own specific view?

Comment: I am not intending to create a seperate view,but i would like to write it into a file. view is not important. I just want to get the references. as objets is also fine.For your first question yes i have used it too. I do not mind using wither of these searches

Comment: How are you going to drive it? Is it from selecting a some IJavaElement(s)?

Comment: Looks like a there could be a hacky way of doing it via running the search from the FindReferencesAction, then accessing the search results from the search query

Comment: I will be having a list of strings containing class names for which i need to find the references in a given project

Answer (score 0):

Before you write anything like this, make sure you take a look at [JDepend4Eclipse](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/jdepend4eclipse/), it may do much of what you need. I have used it in the past to do package-level refactoring as well as understanding (and removing) circular dependencies.

If it doesn't do what you need, you may want to peek at their source code.