# Generate a call graph for a java program - Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, call-flow

Is there any sort of support in Eclipse whereby I can programatically generate a static call graph for a single method in a class, at build time?

I would like to be able to determine all of the methods that may be potentially called from a given class method.

I am not interested in a visual graph. I'm looking for an API. It doesn't even have to be Eclipse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eclipse has something called a `Call Hierarchy`. Highlight your method, right click and select `Open Call Hierarchy`. In addition in Windows you can use the keyboard shortcut `CTRL+ALT+H`.

Comment: Thanks for this. Do you know if this is available via an API?

Comment: Take a look at this SO question and see if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321290/invoking-call-hierarchy-from-eclipse-plug-in

Answer (score 2):

Call heirarchy and call graph are different. Eclipse "Call Heirarchy" will provide backward trace. Where Call graph is forward trace. "Modal goon" plugin provides this feature.

Comment: Call Hierarchy provides forward trace as well. Click the "Show Callees" button. http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fcdt_u_call_hierarchy_view.htm